# What exactly is this op amp being used to do? Bandpass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, circuit-analysis, reverse-engineering

I am trying to identify the major functions of the different portions of this "clap on, clap off" circuit for a project. It's unclear to me what the purpose is of the section circled in orange.

I understand that the second op amp's purpose is to be a half wave rectifier and that the third op amp is meant to be a difference amplifier, but the purpose of the first op amp (IC1A) is not very clear. Any help or corrections to my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Here is the full schematic for this circuit]

Comment: The orange part looks like an active low pass filter to filter HF noise. Which makes sense as the blue part before it is not really a filter. The small AC signal generated by the mic should pass right through C3. At the (+) of the IC1A you should have the AC spike with a 4.5V dc offset.

Answer (score 4):

Blue: Mic bias.

Orange: Amplifier, 10x if transistor is off, 100x if transistor is on. R7/C9 is a low pass filter, just to attenuate high-frequency noise. C6 is needed to block the DC in the feedback path, remember that the previous stage has biased the signal path to about 1/2 Vcc.

Green: Precision rectifier.

Purple: Peak detector & Comparator (positive feedback).

General comment: this is a waste of computing power. A clever designer would move more of the functions into the MCU.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, everything you explained makes complete sense now looking at the circuit, but I do have one more question. This is more of an applicational question, but what would be the circumstances in which the microcontroller outputs the gain causing the transistor to turn on?